# Can a weakly consistent iterator throw NoSuchElementException after it has responded true to hasNext method?

Tags: java

I am using a weakly consistent iterator provided by a Concurrent map. I have a question whether it can throw NoSuchElementException for next() method call after responding to hasNext() method as true value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From HashMap documentation:**

```
public Collection<V> values()
```

The view's iterator is a **"weakly consistent"** iterator that will never throw ConcurrentModificationException, and **guarantees to traverse elements as they existed upon construction of the iterator**.

So, you shouldn't get any `NoSuchElementException` after `hasNext()` returns `true`.